# how to tackle design issue when user changes font size in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, font-size

Well, android users changes font size normal to large or huge, the design my app goes out. I am using Relative Layout as Parent

here are two images which will clear the difference

**when design looks good**

[image]

**when font is changed to large or huge,**

[image]

Comment: man.. scary.. I just released my app, and you killed my sleep..

Comment: Users can do a lot of things with system from installing new fonts to using custom ROMS with modified framework resources. You can't be responsible for a setting you didn't provide as a preference in your App. Though You can hard code test size in your layout. In your layout, if that overlapping area is scrollable, then its fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `RelativeLayout` for this kind of layout is a bad idea,a user with a small screen will not see the bottom of your layout.
I recommand you to use `ScrollView` under your header instead

Comment: Yes, this is the possible solution. adding scrollView.